# elsarticle: How to get bibliography sorted alphabetically?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, elsarticle

How can one get the bibliography items to appear in alphabetical order (by last name) in `elsarticle` (based on Natbib afaik). Below is a MWE. The expected outcome is the two entries appearing interchanged (so 'F. Bar' before 'B. Foo').

```
\documentclass[times, sort&compress, 3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{mykey1,
   author = {Foo, B.},
   journal = {Journal of LaTeX questions},
   pages = {1--10},
   title = {{Minimal title}},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   year = {2017}}
@article{mykey2,
   author = {Bar, F.},
   journal = {Journal of LaTeX questions},
   pages = {1--10},
   title = {{Minimal title}},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\cite{mykey1}, \cite{mykey2}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `elsarticle-num` bib style does *not* perform alphabetical sorting. If you don't have to use this bib style; don't.

For an alternative to `elsarticle-num`, you might consider the `abbrvnat` bib style. If you do so, be sure to also specify the document class option `numbers` (which will be passed to the `natbib` package).